# Problems sending fragment identifier (hash) to PHP via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to get the hash people are using to visit our page with, to create some content data with. Most times the hash will be something like `#IF5533`. As I know that the hash is user-side only, I need to get that hash into a PHP string.

So far I got this code done (hash.js):

```
var data = window.location.hash;
jQuery.ajax({
url: 'hash.php',
type: 'post',
data: {data: data},
success: function(response){
console.log(response);
}
});
```

My hash.php looks like this:

```
$value = $_POST[data];
echo $value;
```

My problem is that I can't use `$value` anywhere in my code, as it appears empty.  Where am I going wrong or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` will show you what your script _actually_ receives. And please set your error_reporting to a sensible value, so PHP can tell you straight away when you are trying to access values that aren’t there.

Comment: i know about print_r ... it get's me Array
(
    [data] => #handbold
) as it should ... but I still can't get the data back to my index.php page and use it...

Comment: What do you mean by “getting it back to your index.php”?

Comment: im running the hash.js file from index.php ... i need to use the responce from hash.php later in the index.php file

Comment: You can not use it “later” within the same script instance, because your `index.php` PHP script has already finished running a long time before, before your index.php was output to the browser.

Comment: So there is no way i can use the info from the hashtag when generating the page with PHP?

Comment: Not without reloading the page, no. The other option would be to load the actual content you want to display via AJAX, and then put it into the document.

Comment: FYI, this is not a "hashtag". That's the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), commonly called "hash". A hashtag is something you use in Twitter message to categorize the message.

Answer (score 0):

First check if window.location.hash not is empty, with the firebug or your inspector:

```
 console.log(window.location.hash);
 // or
 console.log(window.location);
```

Second check the POST data in your php file:

```
 echo "<pre>". print_r($_POST, true). "</pre>";
```